# Microsoft Access 2013 Button Issue

Tags: ms-access

I have kind of a two part issue (they may be related, I'm not sure). I've never worked with Microsoft Access 2013 before (or any Access version really), and using a "for dummies" type book I'm trying to build a front end interface to link to a SQL database.  To do this I'm using the navigation form, regular forms, and then the tables themselves in subforms within that. The forms that hold the subforms are also where I'm placing my buttons. My intentions with these buttons are to use them to filter the table to specific records.  I have one doing that successfully (via the main navigation form) but then I have the problem of all the other buttons not working at all, or calling the same text box that that one calls.

*This is the code to the working button:*

[image: Search Mill ID Button]

I added the stop Macros actions in an effort to keep the same box from popping up when I pressed another button that houses the macro with a show all records action.  Because of issues I also added a stop macro action before the show all records actions on this button (I would do a picture but I'm only allowed two links per the site rules).

This one I found when I added the stop action to the macro before the show all action it stopped the box from popping up, but it also doesn't work to show me all the records. Without the stop action, it acts exactly like the Search Mill ID Button.

The second part of my issues is that my third button currently does show me all records despite it being me trying to use it as a search feature to have a box pop up and the user enter in all or part of a company name to filter the records.

*That code looks like this:*

[image: Company Name Search Button]

I am pretty sure there are a few things wrong with the code on this button in general, but have been having trouble finding any resources of people who are having the same problems as me (or perhaps the issue is so basic most users just automatically know what to do).  I've been relying on youtube videos and an access for dummies book to try to build this stuff, but realize that I'm a little beyond my skills; however, I still have to get it done for my job so I'm persevering through.

I appreciate any tips/suggestions to help!

Comment: You're using parameters to filter your form, which is fine, but that's why the pop-up opens each time a button is pressed, because the source is getting refreshed and it won't remember the previous entry. Typically, devs will build controls on the form where you can specify either the Mill ID or Company Name from a combobox, and the sources for your subforms would include a permanent reference to those controls to filter the the form. See [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/forms/filter_form2007.php) link for a sample of how this is done. For walkthroughs you should find some on google.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to set the OnClick event of your button to use VBA code (Event Procedure), and get the Mill_Id from an Input Box. Macros are much more limiting than VBA and you cannot reasonably use error handling. You can then set the RecordSource property of the form when the button is clicked. The buttons OnClick event would be something like this:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
        s = InputBox("What is the Mill ID?", "Mill ID", "")
        Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM MyTableWithMillData WHERE Mill_ID = '" & s & "'"
End Sub
```

Or if the button is on a parent form, and you're trying to change the subform, use this:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
        s = InputBox("What is the Mill ID?", "Mill ID", "")
        Me!subformcontrolname.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM MyTableWithMillData WHERE Mill_ID = '" & s & "'"
End Sub
```